# How to run custom routing for all urls except one special in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have done some URL routing like for some URLs.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ProductDetails",
                "Product/{name}/{*other}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "Details" }
            );
```

above code will route all urls of `/Product/{name}` type to `/Product/Details/{parameter}`. Its working fine, now i want that if i enter the url `/Product/List`, this must be treated via default routing.

And i don't want to create one more route for List.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add constraint for `name` parameter (not equal to List):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetails",
    url: "Product/{name}/{*other}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Details" },
    constraints: new { name = "^(?!List$).*$" }
);
```

this route will not match `/Product/List` url

*UPDATE* if you also want to exclude other names: `^(?!(List|Foo|Bar)$).*$`

Comment: how to add more constraints in this, say List, Edit, Create etc?

Comment: What if I want to have just one of these items opposite of the main question?